# Can't make a redirect to url without the trailing slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess

This is my `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
ServerSignature Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect to index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !HEAD
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Enable compression
<FilesMatch "\.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

# Caching control
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
    Header set Pragma "max-age=86400"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

# Redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# Redirect from www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I would like to add a redirect from URLs with the trailing slashes to the same URLs without the slashes.

I tried the following ways:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)/$
RewriteRule ^[^.]+/$ /%1 [QSA,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

But none of them works

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this one works:

```
RedirectMatch ^(.+)/$ $1
```